# Export to 2nd+ spreadsheet

Tags: export-to-excel, excel-2013, powershell-4.0

I'm using `Export-Csv` to export `[pscustomobject]`s. Then I'm using a second function to convert that into a xlsx. Which works perfect. But what if I wanted to export into the second spreadsheet and rename it to something different?
I know `Export-Csv` doesn't support multi spread sheets.

```bsh
Function SaveAsXLXS
{
    #Hide Old File
    (Get-Item $ResultsFilePath -Force).Attributes = "Hidden"

    #Opens Old File
    $Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
    $Workbook = $Excel.Workbooks.Open($ResultsFilePath)

    #Formating
    if ($GroupsTab.IsSelected -or $OrgBoxesTab.IsSelected)
    {
        $Workbook.Worksheets.Item(1).Columns.Item(1).Font.Bold = $True
        $Workbook.Worksheets.Item(1).Columns.Item(1).Font.Size = 12
    }
    $Workbook.Worksheets.Item(1).Rows.Item(1).Font.Bold = $True
    $Workbook.Worksheets.Item(1).Rows.Item(1).Font.Size = 15
    $Workbook.Worksheets.Item(1).UsedRange.EntireColumn.Autofit()

    #Creates Name for New File
    $ExcelOut = $ResultsFilePath -replace '\.csv$', '.xlsx'
    $dir = Split-Path $ExcelOut
    $FilePathBase = $(Split-Path $ExcelOut -Leaf) -replace '\.xlsx$'
    $FilePath = $ExcelOut

    $n = 1
    while (Test-Path $FilePath) {
        $FilePath = Join-Path $dir $($FilePathBase + "-$n" + '.xlsx')
        $n++
    }

    #Saves New File
    $Workbook.SaveAs($FilePath, 51)

    #Exits Old File
    $Excel.Quit()

    #Removes Old File
    Remove-Item $ResultsFilePath -Force
}
```

Comment: You'd need to modify the second function to do that, obviously. For further help show your code.

Comment: The whole thing is 2300+ lines so, just the "second" function.

Answer (score 1):

You're opening the CSV as a new workbook, so you just need to open the workbook to which you want to add it as well and move/copy the sheet.

```bsh
...
$Workbook = $Excel.workbooks.open($ResultsFilePath)
...

$wb2 = $Excel.Workbooks.Open('C:\path\to\other.xlsx')
$Workbook.Sheets.Item(1).Name = 'whatever'          # rename sheet
$Workbook.Sheets.Item(1).Copy($wb2.Sheets.Item(1))  # copy sheet
$Workbook.Close($false)                             # close CSV without saving
$wb2.Save()                                         # save & close workbook
$wb2.Close()
```

Of course, if you want to insert multiple CSVs into a workbook you'd open the xlsx file just once and save/close it after all sheets were inserted.

If you want to insert sheets from a CSV after a particular sheet in the destination workbook change the [`Copy()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837784.aspx) call to something like this:

```bsh
$Workbook.Sheets.Item(1).Copy([Type]::Missing, $wb2.Sheets.Item(3))
```

Comment: Just like export-csv with a [PSCustomObject] in a variable, I want to be able to paste another [PSCustomObject] in a variable into the 2nd+ Sheet. I don't want to put multiple CSVs into 1 workbook, it is a good idea just inconvient as it'd have to create multiple CSVs to put into that xlsx.

Edit: i am testing your idea right now though, atleast the way I interpreted to work the way i want it to.

Comment: Without knowing where the CSVs (or the data therein) come from that's all I can suggest. Depending on what kind of data you have or where they come from there might be other solutions, but you need to provide more information for that (probably in a new question).